# Parse Distribution Pushes build on device with error "the executable was signed with invalid entitlements"

Tags: parse-platform, distribution, provisioning

Parse Distribution Pushes: when I set Provisioning profile with Distribution profile which I using to submit my app to the App Store, but Xcode build on device with error

> the executable was signed with invalid entitlements

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! We are unable to help you with just this much info - Please provide details of what you have tried, what is the exact exception?

Comment: Added: the Provisioning profile with distribution profile  can't run on device before App store release.  Test it with Ad Hoc.